# Codeigniter custom library and config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Codeigniter :** How to access $config custom array within a custom library, where the corresponding file names of the library and the config are named same ?

> **The custom config file must be auto loading** : You can also pass
>   parameters stored in a config file. Simply create a config file named
>   identically to the class file name and store it in your
>   application/config/ folder. [Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

myclass config file : Resides in `config\myclass.php`

```
$config [ 'myconfig' ] [ 'something' ] = 'my value';
```

MyClass library : Resides in `library\MyClass\MyClass.php`

In the constructor of MyClass: `$this->ci =& get_instance (  );`

If I do this `var_dump ( $this->ci->config->item ( 'myconfig' ) [ 'something' ] );`

> **Then it prints NULL.**

But if I add the following line, then it works `$this->ci->config->load('myclass');`

**Why the config file not auto loading ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
# ../config/myclass.php
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = Array(
    'index1' => 'val1',
    'index2' => 'val2',
    .. and so on
);
```

in your controller:

```
$this->config->load('myclass');
```

Then try:

```
$this->config->item('itemName');
```

Comment: You mean $this->config->item('item name'); ?

Comment: Why I have to load the config ? Shouldn't it be loaded automatically ? I checked with var_dump($this->ci->config), it dumps all the $config, but it doesn't have my variables, but when I $this->config->load('myclass'); then the  var dump dumps my variable too